# How to merge table cells of same values in bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I need to merge the cells of the year which are same into a single under which the months are arranged based on the corresponding year. I tried with getting the count of year and using it as colspan value but it didn't work

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let colItem of YearGrid">{{colItem.Year}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let colItem of YearGrid">{{colItem.Month}}</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

```js
YearGrid = [
  {Month: 'Nov', Year: 2020},
  {Month: 'Dec', Year: 2020},
  {Month: 'Jan', Year: 2021},
  {Month: 'Feb', Year: 2021},
  {Month: 'Mar', Year: 2021}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

so please colspan or rowspan

```css
table{
width: 400px
}

table td,table th{
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>43</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>57</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```